# How to display images in lightning web component using relative path

Tags: lightning-web-components

Mine images are stored in **Documents** directory in my org... Now we are getting JSON where image path to display images in templates is:

> ../servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=015B00009501oiDIWE&&docName=ZAEOADBEAb29b973fee074578a1b7ab35d1d3b4c6&&oid=00DB0000000TaziMAC

Now images path showing in browser with:

> https://avnesh-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/lightning/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=015B00009501oiDIWE&&docName=ZAEOADBEAb29b973fee074578a1b7ab35d1d3b4c6&&oid=00DB0000000TaziMAC

```
<img 
    if:true={item.imgSrc}
    class="img-item"
    src={item.imgSrc}
    alt={item.value} 
    title={item.value} />
```

means appending url:

```
https://avnesh-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/lightning
```

which is **current url path**(in browser for `lwc`)

but not displaying as image at all.

But if I am not using lightning web component, then image path coming with:

```
https:///avnesh-dev-ed--ashakya-lwc.visualforce.com
```

where **ashakya-lwc** is namespace of my org. working fine. I can see images in browser.

So is there something i need to enable for **`lwc`** or is there a way to change url for **`lwc`**.

Please suggest for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Finally*** got solution for this:

`Lightning web component` not expecting **`/lightning/`** in url for image, so working url:

> https://avnesh-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=015B00009501oiDIWE&&docName=ZAEOADBEAb29b973fee074578a1b7ab35d1d3b4c6&&oid=00DB0000000TaziMAC

I have changed my image text url from **JSON**(Removed '**..**') for `lighting web component` with

> /servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=015B00009501oiDIWE&&docName=ZAEOADBEAb29b973fee074578a1b7ab35d1d3b4c6&&oid=00DB0000000TaziMAC